Gradient of a complex-valued function with complex-valued variables
I have to minimize a cost function:
$J = \frac{1}{2} e^* e$, where $e \in C$ is the error between the output of my ML model $y \in C$ and the desired value $m \in C$. Therefore, e is a complex number. The * operator represents the complex conjugate.
I will do this minimization by using gradient descent backpropagation. So, I need to find the value of the gradients for each matrix of my model.
By reading about Wirtinger derivatives, I know that:
$\nabla_g Z = 2 \frac{\partial Z}{\partial g^*} = \frac{\partial Z}{\partial Real(g)} + i \frac{\partial }{\partial Img(g)}$ and this would be the backpropagated accordingly.
Here is my question:
Suppose I need $\nabla_{W_2} J $. Knowing that $e = m-y$,
and $y = W_2 \, x$, where $x, y \in C^n$ and $W_2 \in C^{1xn}$, I could use the Frobenius product. The $H$ operator means the conjugate transpose:
$\eqalign{
 J &= e^*:e \\
 J &= (m-y)^*: m-y \\
 J &=  (m-y)^T :(m-y)^H \\
 dJ &=  - (m-y)^T : dy^H  \, \, \, (line 1) \\ 
 dJ &=  - (m-y)^T : x^* d {W_2}^*  \, \, \, (line 2) \\
\frac{\partial{J} }{\partial {W_2}^* } &=  - (m-y)^T \, x^H
}$
Therefore, the gradient would be:
$ \nabla_{W_2} J  =  -  2 (m-y)^T \, x^H $
So, my gradient descend update would be:
$W_2 \textrm{<-} W_2 + \eta * \nabla_{W_2} J $
Here is my question: Is it correct to propagate the gradient as I did from line 1 and line 2? Should I always propagate trying to get only the partial derivative with respect to the conjugate variable?
Edit: everything is complex... $e, m, y, x, W_2$

$
\def\R#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\a{\alpha}  \def\b{\beta}  \def\l{{\large\eta}}
\def\g{\gamma}  \def\e{\varepsilon}
\def\k{\otimes} \def\h{\tfrac12}
\def\q{\quad}   \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q}
\def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\BR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\cc#1{\color{green}{#1}}
\def\CCLR#1{\cc{\LR{#1}}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
$Let's use a convention in which a Greek letter denotes a scalar, an uppercase letter a matrix, and a lowercase letter a $\,\c{\sf column}$ vector.
This renames the following problem variables
$\;\LR{J,e,m,y,W_2^T} \to \LR{\b,\e,\mu,\g,w} $
Rewrite the error function and calculate its differential and gradient
$\big($in the Wirtinger sense$\big)$
$$\eqalign{
\e &= \LR{\g-\mu} \qiq d\e = d\g = x^Tdw \\
\b &= \h\e^*\e \\
d\b &= \h\e^*d\e \;+\; \h\e\,d\e^* \\
&= \h\e^* {x^Tdw} \;+\; \h\e\,{x^Hdw^*} \\
&= \CLR{\h\e^*x}^Tdw \;+\; \CCLR{\h\e x^*}^T{dw^*} \\
\grad{\b}w &= \c{\h\e^*x} \qif \grad{\b}{w^*} = \cc{\h\e x^*} \\
}$$
A gradient descent iteration for $w$ would look like this
$$\eqalign{
w_{k+\o} &= w_k - \l_k\LR{\h\e_k^*\,x} \\
k &= k+\o \\
}$$
NB: If you prefer Frobenius products, feel free to replace my transpose operations with that notation, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
x^T&dw \;&=\; x:dw \\
x^H&dw^* \;&=\: x^*:dw^* \\
}$$

Thank you. I have two questions: 1) x is complex, so, shouldn't that be a conjugate transpose? 2) You are finding the gradient with respect to $\omega$, but omega is complex as well. So, from the literature, I should calculate the partial derivative with respect to the conjugate $\omega^*$ and not to $\omega$. I don't think the differential rule is applied like this. But I might be wrong. See equation 14 of this document. http://dsp.ucsd.edu/~kreutz/PEI-05%20Support%20Files/complex_derivatives.pdf.
This is yet another reference
https://fluxml.ai/Zygote.jl/latest/complex/

I see why the confusion on your proof.. I have edited the post. I stated before that x and Y were reals, and they are complex. Please take a look at it again. If possible, I would after like to generalize $e$ to be a vector and not a scalar. So, would it be  be better to keep the notation?

@user3284182 I've updated my post.  You should be using the gradient wrt $w$ to solve for $w,,$ and the gradient wrt $w^$ when solving for $w^;$

@user3284182 BTW the $\mathbb{CR}$-Calculus paper is excellent, and you'll note that my calculation of $d\beta$ uses the techniques in that paper. The second reference is yet another example of the mathematical gobbledygook that infects Machine Learning documentation. The library is undoubtedly very useful but the documentation is confusing.

@user3284182 And if you're programming in Julia you should be aware that $X^*$ is expressed as conj(X),  $X^T$ as conj(X') or permutedims(X),  and $X^H$ as X'

Thanks so much! This is so clear. my only doubt now is $==^T$. Shouldn't this be: $==^H$

@user3284182 If $;\gamma=W_2x = w^Tx=x^Tw;$  how would the Hermitian conjugate $(x^H)$ enter into $d\gamma?;$

You are right. The only point I could not understand is that you are updating $\omega$ and $\omega$*. But how these two updates compose the update to W2?  We are not talking about real and imaginary parts, right?

$W_2$ is a row vector, and $w$ is a column vector.  I changed the name because I think row vectors (and unnecessary subscripts) are annoying.  Both vectors are $\sf Complex$. They are transposes of one another, i.e. $;w^T=W_2;$

I will accept your answer, but I have a final question. Why do you transpose whatever comes before the differential to get the gradient? For example, from $ d\beta = e^* {x^Tdw} $ to $ \grad{\b}w =e^*x$

In the gradient descent method you must add the gradient to the column vector $w$, so the gradient  must be a column vector.  But in order to multiply the gradient by the column vector $dw$ you must transpose it.
